How to decrypt an encrypted incoming webhook payload
I have set up a webhook in an external system to send data to my salesforce sandbox.
My sandbox is getting the webhook payload but its encrypted.
This is my Apex Class
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/myservice/*')
global class MyService {
    @HttpPost
    global static responseWrapper doGet() {
        RestRequest req = restContext.request;
        responseWrapper responseJSON = new responseWrapper();
        System.debug('req: ' + req);
        System.debug('req headers: ' + req.headers);

        String data = '';
        System.debug('data before: ' + data);
        
        Map<String, Object> body = new Map<String, Object>(); // placeholder for the JSON body of the request
    
        String jsonBody = req.requestBody.toString(); // the body of the request
        
        body = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonBody); // deserializes the JSON string into collections of primitivr data types
        data = (String)body.get('data');
        System.debug('data after: ' + data);
 
        
        System.debug('body: ' + body);
        return responseJSON;    
    }
    
    global class responseWrapper {
        global String data{get;set;}      
    }
}

and this is what the configuration on the webhook site looks like

As you can see, there is a 'SECRET KEY' that is on the webhook setup UI but I dont know how to use this for my use case.
I set up some debug logs and tested the webhook and these are the logs that were generated.
USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|req: RestRequest:[headers={CipherSuite=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLSv1.3 443, Content-Type=application/json, Host=xxxxxxx--webhook.sandbox.my.salesforce-sites.com, User-Agent=GuzzleHttp/7, Via=HTTP/1.1 sfdcedge, X-B3-ParentSpanId=19d6841f81ad29d2, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-SpanId=c974625bd1ace698, X-B3-TraceId=973f05c281d1bc974358612c47422ff4, X-Edge-Next-Hop=origin, ...}, httpMethod=POST, params={}, remoteAddress=52.200.115.22, requestBody=Blob[351], requestURI=/myservice, resourcePath=/services/apexrest/myservice/]
18:06:27.1 (7856642)
USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|req headers: {CipherSuite=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLSv1.3 443, Content-Type=application/json, Host=xxxxxx--webhook.sandbox.my.salesforce-sites.com, User-Agent=GuzzleHttp/7, Via=HTTP/1.1 sfdcedge, X-B3-ParentSpanId=19d6841f81ad29d2, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-SpanId=c974625bd1ace698, X-B3-TraceId=973f05c281d1bc974358612c47422ff4, X-Edge-Next-Hop=origin, ...}*
USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|data before:
USER_DEBUG|[19]|DEBUG|data after: eyJpdiI6Ik5xY29hMUxEaWF1c3B0S09oc2E4NkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQ2U0cTQ4NDJYODV6WkgwbU1kcHI2YjZMT050MjBvaG5jVFNhdVRxWlVnbHVSUzBpSXBQT2FQRCs0VHFSR1lxeS9xNnZYMnNiWGFpMWNtRnNTUEFGVmc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjczMWFlZjM5MjVlMzY2ZDMzMjU3NTgyYWRhMGRhMmM0YjM1MDA4ZDU5Yjk1ZjI5NjE1NDVjYWI3ZmViNjFiYzQiLCJ0YWciOiIifQ==
USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|body: {action=updated, data=eyJpdiI6Ik5xY29hMUxEaWF1c3B0S09oc2E4NkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQ2U0cTQ4NDJYODV6WkgwbU1kcHI2YjZMT050MjBvaG5jVFNhdVRxWlVnbHVSUzBpSXBQT2FQRCs0VHFSR1lxeS9xNnZYMnNiWGFpMWNtRnNTUEFGVmc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjczMWFlZjM5MjVlMzY2ZDMzMjU3NTgyYWRhMGRhMmM0YjM1MDA4ZDU5Yjk1ZjI5NjE1NDVjYWI3ZmViNjFiYzQiLCJ0YWciOiIifQ==, id=xxx, table=demographics}
So as you can see, the 'body' of the payload is one giant string which I assume needs to be decrypted, but I dont know how. Any help is appreciated

How the other side encrypts it (if at all) kinda matters here. The term "secret key" is largely meaningless on its own. Please read the docs of your external service, then edit your question and provide this detail.

Data is a base-64 encoded string, and the secret key appears to be a 256-bit private symmetric key (just guessing, based on the length). As such, you're going to need to first use EncodingUtil.base64decode on both the data property and the secret key (which you'll need to store in Salesforce somewhere), and then decrypt the data using Crypto.decrypt or possibly Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV, probably using AES256 as the cypher mode. Unfortunately, since you redacted some data, we're not able to validate the precise procedure, though I hope this is enough to get you started.
